# Restructuring array with nested objects based on Id and ParentId. Removing empty based on property

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a flat array that i nest together based on childrens parentFolderId. I need to remove items where none of the children, or children's children below it contains the property in_shop

My example data looks like this:

```
const menuItems = [
  {
    id: 1,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: null,
    // ... rest of object
  },
    {
    id: 2,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 6,
    // ... rest of object
  },
    {
    id: 3,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 2,
    in_shop: true
    // ... rest of object
  }, 
    {
    id: 4,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 1,
    // ... rest of object
  },
    {
    id: 5,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 1,
    // ... rest of object
  },
    {
    id: 6,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: null,
    // ... rest of object
  },
    {
    id: 7,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 5,
    in_shop: true,
    // ... rest of object
  },
    {
    id: 8,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 3,
    // ... rest of object
  },
  // ... rest of objects
];
```

I want a result that looks like this, based on the input above:

```
const menuItems = [
  {
    id: 1,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: null,
    // ... rest of object
    children: [
      {
        id: 5,
        displayName: "Equipment",
        parentFolderId: 1,
        children: [
          {
            id: 7,
            displayName: "Equipment",
            parentFolderId: 5,
            in_shop: true,
            // ... rest of object
          },
        ]
        // ... rest of object
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    id: 6,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: null,
    // ... rest of object
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        displayName: "Equipment",
        parentFolderId: 6,
        // ... rest of object
        children: [
          {
            id: 3,
            displayName: "Equipment",
            parentFolderId: 2,
            in_shop: true,
            // ... rest of object
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  // ... rest of objects
]
```

I cant wrap my head around how to recursively loop from the bottom of the array, then back up.

My code that sorts array under children looks like this:

```
function addChild(obj) {
    // get children and further retrieve its children with map recursively
    let children = menuItems.filter(a => a.parentFolderId == obj.id).map(addChild)

    // if children are found then add childs in object ALso check if item is in shop
    if (children.length > 0 ) {
      return { ...obj, children }
    }

    // if no children found then return object only
    return { ...obj }
  }
const result = menuItems.filter(a => a.parentFolderId == null).map(addChild)
```

Comment: You mean like `children.filter(a => a.in_shop || a.children)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reduce the tree by looking to children and property `in_shop`.

```js
const
    menuItems = [{ id: 1, displayName: "Equipment", parentFolderId: null }, { id: 2, displayName: "Equipment", parentFolderId: 6 }, { id: 3, displayName: "Equipment", parentFolderId: 2, in_shop: true }, { id: 4, displayName: "Equipment", parentFolderId: 1 }, { id: 5, displayName: "Equipment", parentFolderId: 1 }, { id: 6, displayName: "Equipment", parentFolderId: null }, { id: 7, displayName: "Equipment", parentFolderId: 5, in_shop: true }, { id: 8, displayName: "Equipment", parentFolderId: 3 }],
    temp = function (data, root) {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(o => {
            Object.assign(t[o.id] = t[o.id] || {}, o);
            ((t[o.parentFolderId] ??= {}).children ??= []).push(t[o.id]);
        });
        return t[root].children;
    }(menuItems, null),
    shop = (r, { children = [], ...o }) => {
        children = children.reduce(shop, []);
        const sub = children.length
            ? { children }
            : {};
        if (o.in_shop || sub.children) r.push({ ...o, ...sub });
        return r;
    },
    tree = temp.reduce(shop, []);

console.log(temp);
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**With a path**

```js
const
    menuItems = [{ id: 1, displayName: "Equipment", parentFolderId: null }, { id: 2, displayName: "Equipment", parentFolderId: 6 }, { id: 3, displayName: "Equipment", parentFolderId: 2, in_shop: true }, { id: 4, displayName: "Equipment", parentFolderId: 1 }, { id: 5, displayName: "Mic", parentFolderId: 1 }, { id: 6, displayName: "Equipment", parentFolderId: null }, { id: 7, displayName: "Accessories for mic", parentFolderId: 5, in_shop: true }, { id: 8, displayName: "Equipment", parentFolderId: 3 }],
    format = string => string.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-'),
    temp = function (data, root) {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(o => {
            Object.assign(t[o.id] = t[o.id] || {}, o);
            ((t[o.parentFolderId] ??= {}).children ??= []).push(t[o.id]);
        });
        return t[root].children;
    }(menuItems, null),
    shop = (p = '') => (r, { children = [], ...o }) => {
        const path = p + (p && '/') + format(o.displayName);
        children = children.reduce(shop(path), []);
        const sub = children.length
            ? { children }
            : {};
        if (o.in_shop || sub.children) r.push({ ...o, path, ...sub });
        return r;
    },
    tree = temp.reduce(shop(), []);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but i have to say the code is little above my head.
Would you mind commenting the code to explain the process and methods? It would be very educational!

Comment: the first part, assigning to `temp` is building a tree by using both references of the object and the parent at the same time. if you take a viee to `t` in `forEach`, you get the idea how this works. the result is a tree even if the data is unordered. `shop` is a function for reducing an array of certain level. it smply checks the children an or the property and returns the tree with only leaves which contains `in_shop: true` and the parents of it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. The code is quite complex for me to grasp at this point. 

Can i easily add a property to the children like this:
child.path = allParentsBefore.path+child.name ?

Comment: how should it look like after for an inner name property?

Comment: Basically like this:
https://pastebin.com/VJqPVF3z

So that i get a proper url based on the position in the array.

Comment: please see edit.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the return value as follows:

```
return { ...obj, children, in_shop: obj.in_shop || children.some(child => child.in_shop) }
```

Answer (score 1):

For each an `in_shop` item walk through parents (with caching in an object). Since the order of `in_shop` items seems random - sort the result by `id`:

```js
const map = {};
const result = [];

const walk = item => 
  !item.parentFolderId && result.push(item) || // add root items to the result
  map[item.parentFolderId]?.children.push(item) || // if cached, just add to children
  walk(map[item.parentFolderId] = {...menuItems.find(({id}) => id === item.parentFolderId), children: [item]});
  
const sort = items => items?.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id).forEach(({children}) => sort(children));

menuItems.forEach(item => item.in_shop && walk({...item}));
sort(result);

console.log('original array is preserved:', JSON.stringify(menuItems) === originalJSON);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
const menuItems = [
  {
    id: 1,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: null,
    // ... rest of object
  },
    {
    id: 2,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 6,
    // ... rest of object
  },
    {
    id: 3,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 2,
    in_shop: true
    // ... rest of object
  }, 
    {
    id: 4,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 1,
    // ... rest of object
  },
    {
    id: 5,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 1,
    // ... rest of object
  },
    {
    id: 6,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: null,
    // ... rest of object
  },
    {
    id: 7,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 5,
    in_shop: true,
    // ... rest of object
  },
    {
    id: 8,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 3,
    // ... rest of object
  },
  // ... rest of objects
];
const originalJSON = JSON.stringify(menuItems);
</script>
```

```
` Chrome/119
------------------------------------------------------------
Alexander        1.00x  |  x1000000  316  325  336  367  397
Nina Sholz       3.35x  |   x100000  106  110  111  116  125
------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const menuItems = [{
    id: 1,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: null,
    // ... rest of object
  }, {
    id: 2,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 6,
    // ... rest of object
  }, {
    id: 3,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 2,
    in_shop: true
    // ... rest of object
  }, {
    id: 4,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 1,
    // ... rest of object
  }, {
    id: 5,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 1,
    // ... rest of object
  }, {
    id: 6,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: null,
    // ... rest of object
  }, {
    id: 7,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 5,
    in_shop: true,
    // ... rest of object
  }, {
    id: 8,
    displayName: "Equipment",
    parentFolderId: 3,
    // ... rest of object
  }];
  
//@benchmark Nina Sholz
const temp = function (data, root) {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(o => {
            Object.assign(t[o.id] = t[o.id] || {}, o);
            ((t[o.parentFolderId] ??= {}).children ??= []).push(t[o.id]);
        });
        return t[root].children;
    }(menuItems, null),
    shop = (r, { children = [], ...o}) => {
        children = children.reduce(shop, []);
        if (!children.length) children = undefined;
        if (o.in_shop || children) r.push({ ...o, children });
        return r;
    };
temp.reduce(shop, []);
  
//@benchmark Alexander
const map = {};
const result = [];

const walk = item => 
  !item.parentFolderId && result.push(item) || // add root items to the result
  map[item.parentFolderId]?.children.push(item) || // if cached, just add to children
  walk(map[item.parentFolderId] = {...menuItems.find(({id}) => id === item.parentFolderId), children: [item]});
  
const sort = items => items?.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id).forEach(({children}) => sort(children));

menuItems.forEach(item => item.in_shop && walk({...item}));
sort(result);
result;

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```